# Getting list of all users from Database using php PDO

Tags: php, json, pdo

I am trying to get a list of players from database with specific range of latitude and longitude. The query works fine and give me results. However these results may include more than one player. Current code as shown below gives me JSON Encoded only one player. How can I get all players JSON ENCODED.

```
function GetPlayersInRange() 
    {
        try {
            $conn = $this->GetDBConnection();

            $long1 = trim($_REQUEST['long1']);
            $long2 = trim($_REQUEST['long2']);
            $lat1  = trim($_REQUEST['lat1']);
            $lat2  = trim($_REQUEST['lat2']);


            $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM players WHERE longitude > :long1 AND longitude < :long2 AND latitude > :lat1 AND latitude < :lat2');
            $statement->bindParam(':long1', $long1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->bindParam(':long2', $long2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->bindParam(':lat1' , $lat1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->bindParam(':lat2' , $lat2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->execute();

            if(!($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) 
            {
                return "No Players";
            }

            $conn = null;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            throw $e;
        }

        return $row;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$statement->fetch` to `$statement->fetchAll`. [Fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) will only "Fetch the next row from a result set" whereas [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) will "Return an array containing all of the result set rows".

Comment: Thanks that did it.i thought i had to do some changes with FETCH_ASSOC

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be comparing string to int/double in your query. When using PDO::PARAM_STR, it'll wrap your data in single quotes. Try to use PDO::PARAM_INT here.

Comment: Anyway - how are you going to compare strings with ">"?

Comment: funny thing is, it was doing precise search even by using PARAM_STR. I have changed it to INT either way works as it should.